# Having trouble getting Bootstrap datepicker to display

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to incorporate a bootstrap date picker into my HTML form, but it isn't working as expected.

**HTML**

```
<div class="submit-row">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file_text.php" method="post" class="form-group">
        <div class="submit-column">
            <br>
            <input name="ip_uploaded" type="file" class="inputfilebutton"/>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class ="submitter" name="submit" >Analyze</button>
            <br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="submit-column">
            <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
        clickInput: true
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to attach the datepicker to an element with the class 'datepicker', but you do not have an element with that class.

Comment: this is not answer, this statement are write in comment section not in answer section